# VBA/MSAccess loop for counting sum from specific rows to form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created form in MS Access which contains 20 records. To every record was added textbox with name "txt". I wrote function in Visual Basic which count specified variable (sum of few rows from col Number) for each person by Person_ID. I'd like to display this specified variable for each person in this textbox.

| Person_ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 |
| 1 | 300 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 400 |
| 2 | 500 |

The Code is below:

```
Dim vSum As Integer
Dim cryterium As String
Dim x As Integer
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table", dbOpenSnapshot)
For x = 1 To 20
    cryterium = "Person_ID = " & x
    rs.FindFirst cryterium
    Do Until rs.NoMatch
        vSuma = vSum + rs!Number
        rs.FindNext cryterium
    Loop
    txt = vSum
    vSum = 0
Next x
```

**Now I get:**

| Person_ID | txt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 900 |
| 2 | 900 |

**I want:**

| Person_ID | txt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 600 |
| 2 | 900 |

How can I get sum of few rows for every person?

Comment: Is it in a table? You can query with a groupby on Person_ID and a sum on txt

Comment: How exactly should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using this table:

| Person_ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 |
| 1 | 300 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 400 |
| 2 | 500 |

Create a Query with [Person_ID] set to groupby (Click totals at the top of the query builder, groupby is the default all fields will be set to) and [Number] set to sum.

[image]

In your form you'll need to set the control source of your text box to a Dlookup. Mine was

```
=DLookUp("[Qry_Test]![SumOfNumber]","[Qry_Test]","[Qry_Test]![ID] = '" & [TxT_ID] & " '")
```

But you will probably need to tweak that.

This is the result:

[image]

If you don't want an individual record for each [Number] then make the control source of the form the query you made and you can drop the Dlookup.

Comment: Is there another possible way to do this using only VBA? That's very important for me.

Comment: Yes, write the dlookup in vba and assign the result to the textbox. Your approach in the question should work also, you probably just need to tie the name of the box to the iterator, as it looks like its overwriting with the last value. I don't see the actual assignment though so can't say for sure.

Comment: Yes, it's overwriting with the last value. Here is the problem, cos I don't know exactly how to write this in vba so this could work.